# Springboot 3.0.2 | ESAPI 2.2.0.0 | Log4j2 | micrometer tracing - Span ID and Trace ID not attached to logs

Tags: logging, log4j2, esapi, micrometer-tracing

I am trying to print spanId and traceID when logging in my springboot application but not able to see in console. I am using springboot 3.0.2 version and using micrometer tracing as cloud-slueth is now deprecated. I am also using ESAPI for secure logging.

I am able to get the span id and trace id through tracer and was able to print tracer.currentSpan().traceIdString(); but ideally it should be attached to logs automatically through dependencies.

Please find code details below :

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

ext {
    springCloudVersion = "2022.0.1"
    esapiVersion = "2.2.0.0"
    springDocOpenApiVersion = "2.0.2"
    jakartaMailVersion = "2.0.1"
    javaCFEnvBootVersion = "2.4.1"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    api ("org.owasp.esapi:esapi:${esapiVersion}")
    api ("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    api ("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:${springDocOpenApiVersion}")
    api ("com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:${jakartaMailVersion}")
    api ("io.pivotal.cfenv:java-cfenv-boot:${javaCFEnvBootVersion}")
    api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    api ("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave")
    api ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
        exclude group: "org.eclipse.angus", module: "jakarta.mail"
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

ESAPILogger class written as a wrapper for ESAPI :

```
package com.cardinalhealth.framework.logging;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import org.owasp.esapi.Logger;

public class ESAPILogger implements Logger {

    private final Logger logger;

    public ESAPILogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void debug(String message) {
        this.logger.debug(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void debug(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.debug(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void error(String message) {
        this.logger.error(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void error(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.error(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        this.logger.info(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void info(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.info(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void trace(String message) {
        this.logger.trace(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void trace(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.trace(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void warning(String message) {
        this.logger.warning(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void warning(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.warning(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void fatal(String message) {
        this.logger.fatal(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void fatal(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.fatal(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    public void always(String message) {
        this.logger.always(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, message);
    }

    public void always(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameterValues = patchParameterValues(message, params);
        this.logger.always(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, parameterValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.logger.setLevel(level);
    }

    @Override
    public int getESAPILevel() {
        return this.logger.getESAPILevel();
    }

    @Override
    public void fatal(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.fatal(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatal(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.fatal(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFatalEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isFatalEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void error(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.error(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.error(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isErrorEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isErrorEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.warning(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.warning(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWarningEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isWarningEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void info(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.info(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void info(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.info(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInfoEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isInfoEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void debug(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.debug(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void debug(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.debug(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isDebugEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.trace(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.trace(type, message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
        return this.logger.isTraceEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void always(EventType type, String message) {
        this.logger.always(type, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void always(EventType type, String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.always(type, message, throwable);
    }

    /**
     * @param message
     * @param params
     * @return
     */
    private String patchParameterValues(String message, Object... params) {
        String parameters = message;
        try {
            if (params != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    Object param = params[i];
                    if (param != null) {
                        parameters = parameters.replaceFirst("\\{\\}", Matcher.quoteReplacement(param.toString()));
                    } else {
                        parameters = parameters.replaceFirst("\\{\\}", "null");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Absorb the exception occurred while logging
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parameters;
    }

}
```

Sample Controller to test log with span id and trace id :

```
final ESAPILogger logger = new ESAPILogger(ESAPI.getLogger(SampleController.class));

@GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String getHelloWOrld() {
Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
        logger.debug(".....Started ESAPI LOGGER SAMPLE..Trace ID - {}..Span ID - {}...Parent ID - {}...",
                span.context().traceIdString(), span.context().spanIdString(), span.context().parentIdString());
        logger.debug(".....Ended ESAPI LOGGER SAMPLE..Trace ID - {}..Span ID - {}...Parent ID - {}...",
                span.context().traceIdString(), span.context().spanIdString(), span.context().parentIdString());
}
```

Logger pattern :

```
#Logging configuration
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.cardinalhealth=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} [%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %X{mdcData}- %msg%n


# Trace every action
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
```

Result looks like :

```
[DEBUG] 2023-02-07 14:09:09.876 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SampleController [] - .....Started ESAPI LOGGER SAMPLE..Trace ID - 63e2a1d557b798e4db0685f2c77e9799..Span ID - db0685f2c77e9799...Parent ID - null...
[DEBUG] 2023-02-07 14:09:09.876 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SampleController [] - .....Ended ESAPI LOGGER SAMPLE..Trace ID - 63e2a1d557b798e4db0685f2c77e9799..Span ID - db0685f2c77e9799...Parent ID - null...
```

Question : Ideally if Micrometer Tracing is on the classpath, the logs should be automatically correlated so why spanId and traceId is not included in logs automatically under [?] ?

I can see span id and trace id by explicitly calling the tracer.current span.

I tried everything but could not find any result.

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Its strange but found out that its case sensitive.

I fixed by updating my log pattern to below :

```
logging.pattern.console=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} [%X{traceId}] [%X{spanId}] - %msg%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in *general*, since SpringBoot 3.x uses Jakarta Servlet API and jakarta.servlet rather than javax.servlet packages, it will not be compatible with any version of ESAPI. See this [ESAPI discussion](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/768) for more details.